# How to mass 301 redirect urls from captured domain

Tags: redirect

I got an old domain I bought, all the links targeting the site I bought (old forum), were in 
format:

> http://boughtdomain.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=991&extra=

Im installing wordpress on this domain and want to keep all the links with 301.

How can I mass - redirect all the /forum.php? links to main site? I can do that with .htaccess or wordpress plugin, but I dont know how to redirect only those URLs

I dont want to redirect 404 site as its not really ok google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status code **301 Moved Permanently** means "The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI", you should not use it simply because some other content was previous available at that URI.

You should let your web server reply with **404 Not Found** (The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.) or **410 Gone** (The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent.).

Have a look at what the HTTP status methods means in the RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

To do it, you should use your web server (which you have not specified) preferred method (e.g. `.htaccess` files for Apache, `location` directives for nginx, etc).